# Which files are preserved when I upgrade Windows 7 to 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-8.1-upgrade

If I choose to keep "Just personal files" during upgrade to Windows 8.1 which files will really be preserved ?

In the past, when I was upgrading Win7, I've used Windows Easy Transfer (or was it USMT?), which to my disappointment didn't copy whole user profile but only subset of files and registry keys.

I want to preserve 100% of my user account including registry, various DRM licenses, etc.. Will "keep just personal files" do this for me ?

**UPDATE**

Please refrain from speculations and answer only if you are 100% sure (because you did the upgrade). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> If you only want to keep your files (documents, photos, music, movies, and other files), choose Just personal files.

Source: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/upgrade-from-windows-7-tutorial

Does not mention profiles. But further down on same page:

> If you want to keep using a local account
>
> Windows 8.1 is designed to be used with a Microsoft account, so we recommend that you give it a try. Simply put, a Microsoft account is the glue that holds together so many useful features of the new Windows. Without one, you won't be able to, for example, get new apps from the Windows Store, automatically sync your settings and documents between PCs, back up your photos to the cloud so you can get to them from anywhere, or see all your contacts from multiple email and social networking accounts together in the People and Mail apps.
>
> But if you're sure you want to use a local account instead, click Create a new account, and then on the new account page, click Continue using my existing account.

So in that sense your old account appears to be usable.

In the FAQ though they have some further explication:

> Will I be able to keep my files, settings, and apps?
>
> If you're running   You can keep
>
> Windows 8 -> Windows settings, personal files, and most apps
>
> Windows 7 -> Personal files

So as far as I understand you will not be able to keep all your exact settings and DRM's etc upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 8.

Comment: I can read and google. I've asked this question because Microsoft and other websites are very vague while I want 100% sure answer from someone that actually did upgrade.

Comment: As you can see Windows settings are not kept when you upgrade from Win 7 to Win 8 according to Microsofts FAQ. I think this should indicate pretty clearly that the answer to your question is no. But I understand that you would like to hear it from someone with first hand experience.

Comment: I also want to know which files are copied in case it's not exact copy. I've had bad experience with Win7 tool (missed a lot of stuff) but maybe things have improved since then.

Comment: Rule #1: Have a full backup.

Comment: Doesn't help if you use Windows Backup since they dropped it from Windows 8.1 ;-)